# Unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds

Tags: ruby, unix, firefox, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am continuously getting error below error :

```
unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)\n[\"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:90:in `connect_until_stable'\", \"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:55:in block in launch'\", \"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:43:in locked'\", \"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:51:in launch'\", \"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:43:in initialize'\", \"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in new'\",
 \"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in for'\",
 \"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in for'\",
 \"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in initialize'\"...`
```

I am using:

- Firefox version 42.0,
- selenium-webdriver version 2.52.0
- ruby version 1.9.3-p551
- watir-webdriver (0.9.1)

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read "[mcve]" and "[ask]". There are multiple results for this problem when searching the internet. Where have you searched, and what did you try? Why didn't those help?

Comment: Previously My selenium webdriver version was 2.46 and I was getting this error. I googled it and found that I need to update my selenium version so I updated that but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup to yours and what worked for me was to reinstall an older version for Firefox, for example version 32 (I had Firefox v43 and it was not working, same error message as yours).

You can download older Firefox versions from:
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Make sure to turn off auto-update (otherwise it will update automatically to the latest version after you restart it).